# Solar PV seasonal pattern visualization using fanplot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, solar, pv

I want to build some figures using the package fan plot or similar in Python

I want to have a visualization of the intervals running from the darkest shade of the figures for the 50th percentile to the lightest ones at the 10th at the bottom and the 90th at the top intervals. My data is a time series with energy produced from solar PV panels. I want to have something looking like this image.

PV daily production:
[image]

I tried using [this code I found on GitHub](https://github.com/arviz-devs/arviz/issues/2) but I cannot adjust it to my needs.

An example of my data

```
1/1/2021 2:00 | 0
1/1/2021 3:00 | 0
1/1/2021 4:00 | 0
1/1/2021 5:00 | 0
1/1/2021 6:00 | 0
1/1/2021 7:00 | 0
1/1/2021 8:00 | 2
1/1/2021 9:00 | 231
1/1/2021 10:00 | 876
1/1/2021 11:00 | 1426
1/1/2021 12:00 | 1704
1/1/2021 13:00 | 1772
1/1/2021 14:00 | 1666
1/1/2021 15:00 | 1401
1/1/2021 16:00 | 903
1/1/2021 17:00 | 259
1/1/2021 18:00 | 4
1/1/2021 19:00 | 0
1/1/2021 20:00 | 0
1/1/2021 21:00 | 0
1/1/2021 22:00 | 0
1/1/2021 23:00 | 0
2/1/2021 0:00 | 0
2/1/2021 1:00 | 0
2/1/2021 2:00 | 0
2/1/2021 3:00 | 0
2/1/2021 4:00 | 0
2/1/2021 5:00 | 0
2/1/2021 6:00 | 0
2/1/2021 7:00 | 0
2/1/2021 8:00 | 1
2/1/2021 9:00 | 190
2/1/2021 10:00 | 673
2/1/2021 11:00 | 1025
2/1/2021 12:00 | 1205
2/1/2021 13:00 | 1174
2/1/2021 14:00 | 1028
2/1/2021 15:00 | 737
2/1/2021 16:00 | 367
2/1/2021 17:00 | 74
2/1/2021 18:00 | 0
2/1/2021 19:00 | 0
2/1/2021 20:00 | 0
2/1/2021 21:00 | 0
2/1/2021 22:00 | 0
2/1/2021 23:00 | 0
3/1/2021 0:00 | 0
3/1/2021 1:00 | 0
3/1/2021 2:00 | 0
3/1/2021 3:00 | 0
3/1/2021 4:00 | 0
3/1/2021 5:00 | 0
3/1/2021 6:00 | 0
3/1/2021 7:00 | 0
3/1/2021 8:00 | 0
3/1/2021 9:00 | 77
3/1/2021 10:00 | 388
3/1/2021 11:00 | 716
3/1/2021 12:00 | 981
3/1/2021 13:00 | 1150
3/1/2021 14:00 | 1047
3/1/2021 15:00 | 854
3/1/2021 16:00 | 489
3/1/2021 17:00 | 123
3/1/2021 18:00 | 1
3/1/2021 19:00 | 0
3/1/2021 20:00 | 0
3/1/2021 21:00 | 0
3/1/2021 22:00 | 0
3/1/2021 23:00 | 0
4/1/2021 0:00 | 0
4/1/2021 1:00 | 0
4/1/2021 2:00 | 0
4/1/2021 3:00 | 0
4/1/2021 4:00 | 0
4/1/2021 5:00 | 0
4/1/2021 6:00 | 0
4/1/2021 7:00 | 0
4/1/2021 8:00 | 0
4/1/2021 9:00 | 38
4/1/2021 10:00 | 152
4/1/2021 11:00 | 239
4/1/2021 12:00 | 278
4/1/2021 13:00 | 244
4/1/2021 14:00 | 172
4/1/2021 15:00 | 152
4/1/2021 16:00 | 187
4/1/2021 17:00 | 107
4/1/2021 18:00 | 4
4/1/2021 19:00 | 0
4/1/2021 20:00 | 0
4/1/2021 21:00 | 0
4/1/2021 22:00 | 0
4/1/2021 23:00 | 0
5/1/2021 0:00 | 0
5/1/2021 1:00 | 0
```

Thanks in advance for any help you may provide